# Batch Data Extraction Script

Tags: c#, xml, batch-processing

apologies for the newbie question as I am very new to the world of programming etc.

I have a large XML file containing (see link below). It contains an ID number for legal entities (LEI) followed by the ID for their respective parent company.

[Example from the XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmRqK.png)

The yellow is the entity LEI number and the green is the parent company LEI.

I would like to create some sort of batch script or GUI so I can enter a list of entity (green) LEI numbers and then given an output of all the corresponding parent LEI numbers.

Here is the file for anyone wondering: https://leidata.gleif.org/api/v1/concatenated-files/rr/20171025/zip

I am very inexperienced so I am not sure where to start.

Many thanks

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Batch files have no native way to read and write XML. You need to use a scripting or programming language that supports that capability.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire file content to clipboard, then open your visual studio project and go to menu -> edit -> paste special -> paste as xml classes. This will generate a bunch of classes in the file you have currently open. Save this file. Then you use this code to load the file and return the loaded data:

```
public static RelationshipData LoadFile(string fileName)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items));

    RelationshipData data;
    using (Stream r = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        data = (RelationshipData)serializer.Deserialize(r);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Now you should be able to access the file content using the properties of the returned `data` object. Haven't used this method with xml-data that uses prefixes, but I think this will be handled too...

With this data you should build up a dictionary or something like that that suits your needs that maps one ID to the other ID.

*You should really start reading why and how this works...*

**NOT TESTED**

Comment: Ok I will give this a go and try to read up to understand it more comprehensively. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think I got most of the elements.  You need to do some careful checking since there are a lot of nodes.  I added a writer so I can use Beyond Compare to check if I got all the nodes.  Fixed some errors.  Still need some minor tweaks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RelationshipDataRelationshipData));
            RelationshipDataRelationshipData relationshipDataRelationshipData = (RelationshipDataRelationshipData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            wSettings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, wSettings);


            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("rr", "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016");
            ns.Add("gleif", "http://www.gleif.org/concatenated-file/header-extension/2.0");

            serializer.Serialize(writer, relationshipDataRelationshipData, ns);


            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RelationshipData", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipDataRelationshipData
    {
        [XmlElement("Header")]
        public Header header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RelationshipRecords", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
        public RelationshipRecords relationshipRecords { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement("ContentDate")]
        public DateTime ContentDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FileContent")]
        public string FileContent { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RecordCount")]
        public int RecordCount { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Extension", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
        public Extension extension { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Extension", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class Extension
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sources", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/concatenated-file/header-extension/2.0")]
        public Sourses sources { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sources", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/concatenated-file/header-extension/2.0")]
    public class Sourses
    {
        [XmlElement("Source")]
        public List<Source> source { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Source", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/concatenated-file/header-extension/2.0")]
    public class Source
    {
        [XmlElement("ContentDate")]
        public DateTime ContentDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Originator")]
        public string Originator { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("RecordCount")]
        public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RelationshipRecords", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipRecords
    {
        [XmlElement("RelationshipRecord")]
        public List<RelationshipRecord> relationshipRecord { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RelationshipRecord", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipRecord
    {
        [XmlElement("Relationship")]
        public Relationship relationship { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Registration")]
        public Registration registration { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Extension", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
        public Extension extension { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Relationship", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class Relationship
    {
        [XmlElement("StartNode")]
        public Node StartNode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EndNode")]
        public Node EndNode { get; set; }
        public string RelationshipType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RelationshipPeriods")]
        public RelationshipPeriods relationshipPeriods { get; set; }

        public string RelationshipStatus { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RelationshipQualifiers")]
        public RelationshipQualifiers relationshipQualifiers { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Node", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class Node
    {
        public string NodeID { get; set; }
        public string NodeIDType { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipQualifiers", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipQualifiers
    {
        [XmlElement("RelationshipQualifier")]
        public RelationshipQualifier relationshipQualifier { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipQualifier", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipQualifier
    {
        public string QualifierDimension { get; set; }
        public string QualifierCategory { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Registration", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class Registration
    {
        public DateTime InitialRegistrationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime NextRenewalDate { get; set; }
        public string ManagingLOU { get; set; }
        public string ValidationSources { get; set; }
        public string ValidationDocuments { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipPeriods", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipPeriods
    {
        [XmlElement("RelationshipPeriod")]
        public List<RelationshipPeriod> relationshipPeriod { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipPeriod", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipPeriod
    {
        [XmlElement("StartDate")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("EndDate")]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("PeriodType")]
        public string PeriodType { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipQuantifiers", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipQuantifiers
    {
        [XmlElement("RelationshipQuantifier")]
        public List<RelationshipQuantifier> relationshipQuantifier { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class RelationshipQuantifier", Namespace = "http://www.gleif.org/data/schema/rr/2016")]
    public class RelationshipQuantifier
    {
        [XmlElement("MeasurementMethod")]
        public DateTime MeasurementMethod { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("QuantifierAmount")]
        public decimal QuantifierAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("QuantifierUnits")]
        public string QuantifierUnits { get; set; }

    }

}
```